# How can I update a Model field inside DetailView with a button click

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I've created a maintenance App that allows the user to create and view the maintenance details. I have a page "maintenance-details.html" where I show all the details of a particular maintenance.

Here is my **views.py**:

```
class MaintenanceDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'maintenance/maintenance-details.html'
    model = Maintenance

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        contacts_suppliers = ContactsSupplier.objects.filter(supplier__maintenance=self.object)
        hora_atual = datetime.datetime.now()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contacts_supplier'] = contacts_suppliers
        context['hora_atual'] = hora_atual
        return context
```

I have created a button on my template named "Mark as done". My Maintenance model has a BooleandField "done" with the purpose to set the task as done or not. What I'm looking for is the best way to update the model and set the "done" as "True" when the user clicks it.

My **models.py** here:

```
class Maintenance(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(SuppliersCategory, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Category')  # Field name made lowercase.
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Property_Reference')  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=25)  # Field name made lowercase.
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    staffmember = models.CharField(db_column='StaffMember', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, db_column='Supplier')  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='maintenace/', db_column='Photo', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    expirydate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ExpiryDate', blank=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    datecompletion = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateCompletion', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    done = models.BooleanField(db_column='Done', default=False)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Maintenance'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("maintenance:maintenance_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def set_done(self):
        self.done = True
        self.datecompletion = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a form with button something like this in your template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'done' object.pk %}">
    <button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

Then you need urls.py to include the url named 'done'

```
path('/done/<int:pk>', views.done, name="done")
```

and in your views file

```
def done (request, pk):
    maintenance = Maintenance.objects.get(pk=pk)
    maintenance.set_done()
    return redirect ('url to your detail view')
```

Comment: Should that 'done' function be used with FormMixin inside my DetailView, like the example here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659986/django-implementing-a-form-within-a-generic-detailview]

Comment: I've just used a function here rather than a class view so no

Comment: Henry it worked like a charm, but I'm still trying to understand this. Wouldn't it be a good practice to include that function inside my class? Thanks!

Comment: How to do this to accept a models foreign key to a user, and make the `user.is_active = True` when clicking the button? Using a `DetailView` with the model = a model with the foreign key that has a user to it.

Answer (score 1):

you still can use `post` method inside DetailView.
assuming this is your template:

```
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="set_done">Done</button>
</form>
```

then inside your DetailView:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "set_done" in request.POST:
        self.object.set_done()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

if you don't want to reload the page after user click the button, use ajax instead of regular form in your template.